# How can I pass through the it(...).then() function in unit test of solidity

Tags: unit-testing, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

I have been learning solidity about a few days ago. It is very easy and interesting, but it has a lot of problems which can't solve myself. This is one of such problems.
In a source code of a unit test of some contract, I found the it(...).then() function.

```
var DAppToken = artifacts.require("./DAppToken.sol");

contract("DAppToken",  (accounts) => {
    it("transfers taken ownership", async () => {
        const dappTokenInstance = await DAppToken.deployed();
        return await dappTokenInstance.transfer.call(accounts[1], 99999999999999999999999999999);
    }).then(assert.fail).catch((error) => {
        assert( error.message.indexOf("revert") >= 0, "error message must contain revert");
    });
});
```

It was not executed as I expected. I got the following errors.

*TypeError: it(...).then is not a function*

I am not sure about this error.

> How could I help me?

Comment: Have you chained `.then` on the wrong thing? `it` just registers the test, it doesn't return a promise. A promise is apparently returned by `dappTokenInstance.transfer.call`, but then you `await` that anyway so why use `.then`/`.catch` too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.then` should not come after `it`. it must be appended to the returned promise.

```
it("transfers taken ownership", async () => {
        const dappTokenInstance = await DAppToken.deployed();
        return await dappTokenInstance.transfer.call(accounts[1], 99999999999999999999999999999)
       .then(assert.fail).catch((error) => {
          assert( error.message.indexOf("revert") >= 0, "error message must contain revert");
    });
});
```

In this case, `.then` is used after `await` to catch the error. It is kinda `try/catch`